# Admob Native Ad Issue

Tags: android, firebase, admob, integration, native

I want to implement native ad in my project using [Google Ads Samples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/admob/NativeAdvancedExample), but got the error:

> The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date

I don't want to set firebase for this project,so import the Google Mobile Ads SDK by itself.

app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appId"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        return void
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    return void
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'

}
```

I initilized admob in Application class:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
```

I checked a BannerAd with test unit ad and it loaded and displayed perfectly.But the activity contain Native Ad unit crashed.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of emulator.
When I submitted my question, I had only tested the application on the emulator.The error disappeared after ran the app on real device.I'm not sure but it seems the Google service on emulator needs to update.